# How to determine a logic part with python's beautiful soup when crawling

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

So for now on I always had the schema:

```
<h2 class="dot">headline 1</h2>
<p>text</p>
<h2 class="dot">headline 2</h2>
<p>text</p>
```

But it can be that some sites I crawl have the following schema:

```
<h2 class="dot">headline 1</h2>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<h2 class="dot">headline 2</h2>
<p>text</p>
```

I'm crawling it like this:

```
for product in soup.findAll("p"):
```

I see no way to determine if different p elements belong together. Has somebody an idea how I can decide whether one or two p belong to the same logical unit?

One possible way would be to determine if the predecessor html element is p or h2. Is there a good way to find it out?

Comment: Do all the elements belong to the same parent element? I assume what you're saying is you want to split it up into groups of all the <p> elements directly below each <h2> element.

Comment: Yes that would be a solution. How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""
<div>
<h2 class="dot">headline 1</h2>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<h2 class="dot">headline 2</h2>
<p>text</p>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for h2 in soup.findAll("h2"):
    group = []
    node = h2.next_sibling

    while node is not None and node.name != "h2":
        group.append(node)
        node = node.next_sibling

    # Do w/e you want w/ the group
    print group
```

What I did is to go through all the h2 elements, go through their next siblings and append them to a list until either you run out of siblings or hit another h2. If you only want `<p>` elements then you should change:

```
group.append(node)
```

to:

```
if node.name == "p":
    group.append(node)
```

Oh, and as one last final comment. Unless you actually need a list it would be better to actually just do w/e you want w/ the stuff inside the loop instead of adding it to a list, like so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""
<div>
<h2 class="dot">headline 1</h2>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<h2 class="dot">headline 2</h2>
<p>text</p>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for h2 in soup.findAll("h2"):
    node = h2.next_sibling

    print "This h2", h2

    while node is not None and node.name != "h2":
        if node.name == "p":
            print node
        node = node.next_sibling
```

Output:

```
This h2 <h2 class="dot">headline 1</h2>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
This h2 <h2 class="dot">headline 2</h2>
<p>text</p>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response but it is not working. It is putting the p elements in different groups

Comment: Just added some output for clarification. Are you saying you don't get what I get, or that that's not what you want?

Comment: Hey with the change of "if node.name == "p": group.append(node)"" it is working. Very big THX!